# Input for C# changed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Okay so in the video I'm watching for a tutorial on movement, (link here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Wj7rGiX_5Y ) and around 1:31 he used `if(input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))` but Visual Studio doesn't accept input, do you guys know what they changed it to?

Comment: variable = Console.ReadLine()

Comment: It's `Input.GetKey(...)` (capital **I**), presumably a static method on a static class that's part of unity.

Comment: Make sure you have using System.Console or using static System.Console and just have var = ReadLine()

Comment: Okay thanks guys, and yeah I meant to capitalize the I, and does the variable = Console.ReadLine() tell me what the replacement for the Input command is? Because I tried capitalizing it but it didn't work.

Comment: This is not a tutorial community and your question is about technical things -> https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/index.html

Comment: @Cabrra I know it's not a tutorial community, I have googled everywhere and haven't been able to find out what they changed it to, and I figured that there was someone here who could help.

Comment: It looks like he is using MonoDevelop in the tutorial,, and by default most likely is using Mono.  Make sure you have the using UnityEngine statement at the top of your file.

Comment: @MarkHall I'll check and make sure when I get home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out an easier way to do it, for future reference I used this page. https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/multiplayer-networking/creating-player-movement-single-player

Comment: This has nothing to do with the original question. Just to clarify for anyone that comes across this page looking for help. If you create a script outside of Unity or have your template changed you must use using UnityEngine at the top of your script (answer from @Markhall) and there is Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E) or Input.GetButton("stringname") which can be created by editing your inputs in Unity.

Comment: @Alan-DeanSimonds Listen, I was trying to get my thing to take input from the keyboard, this works, it may not be the exact same thing but it works for what's needed.

Answer (score 1):

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))

replace E with whichever key you want

[More reading](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html)

Comment: @TylerTheHero, did this work for you? Mark as the correct answer in case someone else needs this info, or let us know if it didn't work.

Comment: it didn't work. (Sorry for the late response, it just alerted me about your comments.)

Comment: @TylerTheHero Can you paste in the code that you have, and tell what exactly isn't working. The best way to test is is have a Debug.Log and see if the code is actually activating.

Comment: I did edit it and say what I had written, I did find something that may work so I'm going to try it out and I'll see if it works